# Number of comparison during a a closed address hashing?

Tags: hash, hashtable, time-complexity

Initially, all entries in the hash table are empty lists.
All elements with hash address i will be inserted into the linked list h[i]. If there is collision, during hashing of keys, the key will be added to the end of a linkedList.

For the average case of successful search, do i count it when the comparison is to check if the h[i] is null? if it's null it means that the linkedlist is null and it should return not found. Should it be 1 comparison or 0 comparison? in terms of complexity.

Sorry for this stupid question, i'm still learning algorithm complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "big-O" complexity it just doesn't matter, as there is no such thing as "O(2N+1)" complexity (from counting element and pointer comparisons) - it simplifies to O(N), where N is the number of elements in the bucket `h[i]`.  Alternatively, you might say the average big-O complexity across buckets is O(N) where N is *size* / *buckets*, aka *load factor*.

If you're not doing big-O complexity analysis, we can't really tell you what you want to count.  I would point out that comparisons of pointers to `nullptr` are much cheaper than object comparison involving an extra level of indirection or scanning along a large object (e.g. `std::string` objects too long for any Short-String-Optimisation buffer), so can often be neglected.

If in doubt as to what's wanted, I'd suggest you report the comparisons as in *"searching for an element that's not present involves N object value comparisons and N+1 pointer comparisons, where N is the number of elements chained from `h[i]`"*.

If you must give just one expression (for example, some computerised multiple-choice test), I'd suggest a count of element comparisons is likely the desired answer - the number of value comparisons (i.e. 0 for an empty hash bucket), as it's most common to be interested in the complexity as a function of the number of data elements.

Answer (score 0):

0 comparisons. If at h[i] you see a list of one entry and this is a hit (since you analyze successful search), this would be 1 comparison, and so on.